# C# - Closing brackets aren't being recognized

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list, controller, viewmodel

I have a controller method that looks like this

```
    public ActionResult SpecialOrderSummary(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }

            JobOrder jobOrder = db.JobOrders.Find(id);
            if (jobOrder == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            ViewBag.JobOrderID = jobOrder.ID;
            ItemInstance ii = db.ItemInstances.Where(x => x.serialNumber == jobOrder.serialNumber).FirstOrDefault();
            Item item = db.Items.Find(ii.ItemID);

            var vm = new ItemViewModel
            {
                ItemId = item.ItemID,
                ItemName = item.Name,
                Parts = new List<ItemPartViewModel>
                {
                  foreach (ItemHasParts ihp in item.IHP) 
                  {
                      Part part = db.Parts.Find(ihp.PartID);
                      new ItemPartViewModel
                      {
                         PartId = part.ID,
                         PartName = part.Name
                      };
                  }
                } //this is closing method
            }; // this is closing controller
            
            return View(vm);
        }
```

But the closing `}` to the Parts list and the vm aren't closing the right brackets. Instead, the Parts `}` is closing the method while the vm `}` is closing the controller.

Why is this happening? Is there an issue with my syntax?

Comment: `foreach` inside `new List { .... }` looks very suspicious to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yea you can't have a `foreach` loop inside the `Parts` list initialization.

You have to do:

```cs
var vm = new ItemViewModel
{
    ItemId = item.ItemID,
    ItemName = item.Name,
    Parts = new List<ItemPartViewModel>()
};

foreach (ItemHasParts ihp in item.IHP) 
{
    Part part = db.Parts.Find(ihp.PartID);

    vm.Parts.Add(new ItemPartViewModel
    {
        PartId = part.ID,
        PartName = part.Name
    };
}
```

I am surprised the compiler actually let you compile?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're aiming to do here:

```
            Parts = new List<ItemPartViewModel>
            {
              foreach
```

If this is initializing the Parts variable it cannot contain a foreach loop

Collection initializers  need to contain a fixed number of elements. You can use variables and expressions but you must have a definite number of them:

```
var stringList = new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c", "d"+"e", person.Name };
```

The compiler will turn this into a bunch of calls to Add()

If you have some variable number of items you could Add, AddRange or make a LINQ query to form your list:

```
foreach(var person in myPeople)
  stringList.Add(person.Name);

//or
stringList.AddRange(myStringArray);

//or
stringList = people.Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
```

That last one isn't adding to an existing list; it's replacing the list wholesale with another list. If you wanted to add to an existing you could:

```
stringList.AddRange(people.Select(x => x.Name));
```

The result of the LINQ query being an enumerable list of strings